# httplib.HTTPResponse.read() unexpected keyword argument 'amt'

Tags: python

I have a custom HTTP client I use in production done for python3.x.
Now I need the same function done for python2.7. 
I only have problems with one statement:

```
data = response.read(amt = 10 *1024 *1024)
```

where the response is returned by:

```
urllib2.urlopen(request, timeout=timeout)
```

so it is of type

```
httplib.HTTPResponse

httplib.HTTPResponse.read()
```

supports amt as optional parameter of length under python2.7. Still I am getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "D:\eclipse_workspace\py27\wsdconfirmationserver.py", line 152, in <module>
print(customHttpRequest(url="http://test.com/"))
   File "D:\eclipse_workspace\py27\wsdconfirmationserver.py", line 109, in customHttpRequest
   data = response.read(amt = 10 *1024 *1024)                                   
TypeError: read() got an unexpected keyword argument 'amt'
```

Now the funy thing is if I rename read() in the source of httplib.HTTPResponse this function does no fail any-more but obviously I introduce myriads of other problems in the code.
I wander why this happens... seems like a bug in python, but... maybe is something I don't understand. Thank you for your time!

Comment: please, paste the whole traceback.

Comment: thanks, the traceback suggestion actually solved my puzzlement, see the comment for the accepted solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `read()` takes a kwarg, just try passing in the filesize as an integer?

```
data = response.read(10 *1024 *1024)
```

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.read

Comment: Correct, it works, I can see now in the callstack that the response.read is not passed directly to the httplib.HTTPResponse.read() (read [httplib.py:533]) it goes trough an intermediary read in (read [socket.py:380]). This was somewhat counter intuitive to me.